# How to edit text in psd or ai file without photoshop and without illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have two files from the graphic designer: psd file and ai file.
How can I edit the text?
I don't have photoshop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Paint.NET + PSD Plugin

[Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/) is a free image editor for Windows, but it lacks the ability to work with PSD files without also installing the [Paint.NET PSD Plugin](http://www.psdplugin.com/).

> How to install the plugin:
>
> 1. Make sure you have Paint.NET 4.0 or later installed. (Check this in Help -> About.)
> 2. Close Paint.NET.
> 3. Open the PSD Plugin ZIP file, and then copy PhotoShop.dll to: `C:\Program Files\paint.net\FileTypes`
> 4. Restart Paint.NET, which will automatically detect the PSD filetype plugin.

#### Inkscape supports Adobe's .ai format

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is an free, cross-platform (Windows/OS X/Linux) illustration editor that supports Adobe Illustrator's .ai format. A selection of powerful vector graphics editing tools comes as standard. There is excellent support for paths, gradients, layers, alpha transparency and text flow control.

Answer (score 1):

*For Photoshop :*

**GIMP** is a free open-source image editor. GIMP supports the PSD file format out of the box, so you can jump right in after installing the application.

I think you do need the fonts used in the original PSD to edit the text the way you want to.

*For Illustrator (i think) :*

I think **Corel Draw.** It should open CS4 or maybe even CS5.

Or **Acrobat Pro**. If you have the file with PDF Compatibility enabled, you can do limited editing in Acrobat Pro.

I hope this helps you out :)

Comment: GIMP does not support editing text in PSD files - this can be overcome by implementing that (the PSD specification is available), but so far no one has done this.

Comment: Update: I tried it with some PDD files I had that I couldn't use (apparently quite similar/equivalent to PSD).  While GIMP doesn't show them as supported, it does show PSD... and I was able to open the PDDs properly once I went to showing all files.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest way of solving this is to download Photoshop and Illustrator. These applications have a trial period, which should cover you editing the files, discussing revisions with the designer and following up any changes.

Another issue to flag up would be the fonts used in these documents, if you don't have the editing software, you may also not have the fonts used, which would mean when you open these designs, they would change in appearance and not produce the results you're looking for.